# What is the difference between "Limited Debugging Information" and "Debug Information" in Delphi XE5 compiling setting

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Delphi XE5 compiler for Win32 has new setting for Debug Information: **Limited Debugging Information**.

What is the difference between *Limited Debugging Information* and *Debug Information*?

Comment: Perhaps it is visible just to be uniform with Delphi/LLVM compiler ?

Comment: Adrian Gallero's post at https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=597882 suggests that the 'limited' version is what XE4 produces, but no source given. Possibly something to do with Android/iOS compilation? That is what all the debugger changes listed in embarcadero's wiki refer to (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE5#Debugger_Changes_for_XE5). Good to see Delphi documentation still meeting expectations :-/

Comment: The first link is down.

Comment: See Allen Bauer's answer, at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27935657/3164070

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers provide variants of the debug flag that provide different levels of debugging information and optimization. Depending on the options you use when compiling and linking your program, the debugging information available in the program's executable file may range from full to nonexistent. Programs that include shared libraries or other code modules may contain limited debugging information regardless of the compile options you use.

For example, with full debugging information, the debugger can set breakpoints on procedures and functions; it recognizes routine names and knows parameters and values; it can display source code, knows the source file name, and can provide line numbers.

When encountering limited debugging information, the debugger can attempt to set breakpoints by making assumptions from the available information.

If no debugging information is available in the program's executable file, the debugger can allow for machine-level debugging.

Does this help you?

Comment: Is this based in fact or speculation?